# 同じurlで異なる内容のページのhtml要素の取得方法がわかりません。

Tags: python, html, python3, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[PMDAのサイト](https://www.pmda.go.jp/) では [検索フォーム](https://www.pmda.go.jp/PmdaSearch/kikiSearch/) と検索確認のURLが同じなのですが検索確認のhtmlを解析したいです。
下記のコードでは検索確認のhtmlの解析ができず、検索フォームのhtmlを検出してしまうため、
`elem_serch_btn1`のクリックに失敗します。
検索確認のhtmlを解析するにはどうしたらようでしょうか・・？
お教示お願いいたします。

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import openpyxl as op
import datetime
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.pmda.go.jp/PmdaSearch/kikiSearch/")


elem_search_word = driver.find_element_by_id("txtName")
elem_search_word.send_keys("血液照射装置")
elem_search_btn = driver.find_element_by_name('btnA')
elem_search_btn.click()

cur_url = driver.current_url
html = request.urlopen(cur_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup)

time.sleep(5)

elem_serch_btn1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text('//*[@id="ResultList"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/a')
elem_serch_btn1.click()
```

Comment: 西木野有栖さんから編集リクエストを頂いていますが、元々質問者さん本人のアカウントであればご自身の投稿は自由に編集ができます。逆に質問者さん本人のアカウントと分からないと今回のリクエストは通しにくいため、アカウントの確認をしていただきたいです。もしアカウントが2つに分かれてしまったということであれば、[こちらのヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)からアカウントを統合できますので、お試しください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Webサーバーには、サーバーとブラウザ間で固有の情報を共有するためのセッションという仕組みがあり、同じURLにアクセスした場合でも、ブラウザが異れば、異なるページが表示される場合があります。

そのため、最初にページにアクセスしたブラウザを使ってページの情報を取得する必要があります。

ご質問のコードには、`driver`を使って最初にページにアクセスしていますが、途中から別ブラウザとなる`request.urlopen`を使ってURLにアクセスしているため、お望みの情報が取得できないのだと思います。

そこで、以下のように、`request.urlopen`を使わない方式を試されると良いと思います。

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup)
```